# Checkbox array click event JQuery & show label value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display the label text and checkbox value from a checkbox array when each one is clicked (for testing assume i need it to display in an alert)

I have the following HTML

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" id="answers" value="3001"> Option 1</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" id="answers" value="3019"> Option 2</label>
```

I cant figure out the JS to make it work! Help much appreciated!

Comment: IDs must be _unique_.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem is, the list of checkbox's is generated based on previous responses. How would i create the PHP query to insert into the database if the ID is one of 1000 id's?

Comment: Well, in that case you can use HTML5's [`data-*`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attributes instead of `id` attributes. Then for getting the values using jQuery, you can use the `.data()` method.

Comment: Thanks - that looks like something i could use. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this);
        alert(clicked.text() +" === "+clicked.val());
    });
});
```

Ask if u need explanations

Comment: Thanks - this works when a check box already on the page is clicked. However, when it's a checkbox generated by an ajax query, it doesn't work. What could I be missing?

Comment: Simple... When the document is ready, checkbox have there click method binded... If the checkbox is created after that (by your ajax call), there is no click handler... Looks at ".bind" or ".live" in jQuery doc :)

Comment: @user3163357 Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of the deprecated/removed `.live()`.